# Radio and Checkbox Checked Values Won't Show in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button, window.open

I'm trying to get the value of a radio button and multiple checkboxes to appear in a new window using JavaScript. I can't seem to figure out why "true" return instead of the actual value checked. Below is the code and screenshot of the results.

[image]

```js
function messagebox()
{
 var newWindow;
 var msg ="";
 var i = document.PizzaForm.state.options.selectedIndex;
 var text = document.PizzaForm.state.options[i].text;
 var value = document.PizzaForm.state.options[i].value;
 
 { document.PizzaForm.customer.value = document.PizzaForm.customer.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}); }
 
 { document.PizzaForm.city.value = document.PizzaForm.city.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}); }
 
 newWindow = window.open("","","status=no,height=500,width=500");
 message = "<ul><li>Name: " + document.PizzaForm.customer.value;
    message += "<li>Address: " + document.PizzaForm.address.value;
    message += "<li>City: " + document.PizzaForm.city.value;
    message += "<li>State: " + document.PizzaForm.state.value;
    message += "<li>Zip Code: " + document.PizzaForm.zip.value;
    message += "<li>Phone: " + document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
    message += "<li>Email: " + document.PizzaForm.email.value;
 message += "<li>Size: " + showSize();
 message += "<li>Toppings: " + showToppings();
 newWindow.document.write(message);

function showSize()
 {
 for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.sizes.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].checked)
  msg += document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].value;
 return true;
 }
 
function showToppings()
 {
 for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
            msg += (i==0?"":",")+document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
 return true;
 } 
}
```

Comment: it is because you are returning true in the showSize() method. you should be returning msg. same goes for the showtoppings() method.

Comment: *hangs head in shame* It was staring me right in the face, thanks Sushil!

Comment: @Sushil You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Sushil please do so I can give you the credit.

Comment: you're most welcome @DoveOne, I'll post this as an answer. please mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `showSize()` and the `showToppings()` methods are both returning `true` in the end which is why you're getting true in your string. you should return `msg` and your problem will be solved.